# Comparison of ID of 2 dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

In the following program:

```
rec = {"Name":"Python","Age":"20"}
id1 = id(rec)
del rec
rec = rec = {"Name":"Python","Age":"20"}
id2 = id(rec)
print(id1==id2)
```

Python gives the output as `True`.

But I do not understand why is the output so. Even when I change the variable name associated with the dictionary, the keys of the dictionary and also the length of the dictionary, I still get the output as `True` as in the following program:

```
rec = {"Name":"Python","Age":"20"}
id1 = id(rec)
del rec

rec2 =  {"Name2":"Pythonista","Age":"20","Marks":20}
id2 = id(rec2)
print(id1==id2)
```

But when I do not delete the former dictionary, I get the output as False, as in the following program:

```
rec = {"Name":"Python","Age":"20"}
id1 = id(rec)

rec2 =  {"Name2":"Pythonista","Age":"20","Marks":20}
id2 = id(rec2)
print(id1==id2)
```

Why does python give the output is such a way?

I am using Python 3.7.7

Comment: `id` is only guaranteed unique for the lifetime of the object. As an implementation detail, CPython uses the address of the PyObject head, which it is free to reuse, and often does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, you are playing with implementation details here. What the language says is that an object as a unique id, and if two objects have same id, then they are the same. This is mandated by the language.

Whether the id of a deleted object will be re-used by the next created object is clearly a *detail*, depending on the implementation and possibly on other details. So it may be the same or not, and without digging into the source of an implementation you cannot be sure of the result.

Only one thing is sure here, you should not rely on getting the same id.